# How to convert this data to JSON using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am posting a data to a server and it turns out like this.
I wanted to convert this to JSON using javascript.

```
country=Philippines\r\n
countryid=840\r\n
operator=Globe Telecom Philippines\r\n
operatorid=246\r\n
connection_status=100\r\n
destination_msisdn=639358661725\r\n
destination_currency=PHP\r\n
product_list=25,50,150,300,500,1000\r\n
retail_price_list=0.70,1.40,4.10,8.10,13.50,27.00\r\n
wholesale_price_list=0.56,1.10,3.26,6.49,10.80,21.58\r\n
authentication_key=1429269579325\r\n
error_code=0\r\n
error_txt=Transaction successful\r\n
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function string_to_json(s) {
   return JSON.stringify(s.split('\r\n').
   reduce(function(s,a) {r = a.split('=', 2); 
   s[r[0]] = r[1]; return s;}, {}))
}
```

Usage:

```
string_to_json("country=Philippines\r\ncountryid=840\r\noperator=Globe Telecom Philippines\r\noperatorid=246\r\nconnection_status=100\r\ndestination_msisdn=639358661725\r\ndestination_currency=PHP\r\nproduct_list=25,50,150,300,500,1000\r\nretail_price_list=0.70,1.40,4.10,8.10,13.50,27.00\r\nwholesale_price_list=0.56,1.10,3.26,6.49,10.80,21.58\r\nauthentication_key=1429269579325\r\nerror_code=0\r\nerror_txt=Transaction successful\r\n")
```

Output:

```
"{"country":"Philippines","countryid":"840","operator":"Globe Telecom Philippines","operatorid":"246","connection_status":"100","destination_msisdn":"639358661725","destination_currency":"PHP","product_list":"25,50,150,300,500,1000","retail_price_list":"0.70,1.40,4.10,8.10,13.50,27.00","wholesale_price_list":"0.56,1.10,3.26,6.49,10.80,21.58","authentication_key":"1429269579325","error_code":"0","error_txt":"Transaction successful"}"
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: This. It's what I said but written out.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your best way might be to parse that string out (splitting on \r\n) and then split that on the = sign and put them in the correct format for JSON. Adding link for reference.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp